# Loading savedsearch in Suitescript doesnt include all columns. NetSuite

Tags: mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

When loading a saved search in suitescript it doesnt include all columns, for example the summed columns in the end are not included. I tried `getResults` function but because im loading this in `mapreduce` `getInputData` function, because of huge data the script timelimit gets exceeded (SSS_TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED).

From the below screenshot the marked columns are not visible when i:

```
    function getInputData(){
        var mainSrch = search.load({ id: 'customsearch1000' });
        return mainSrch;
    }
```

[image]

Below is the result i get in the script:

```
{
    "recordType": null,
    "id": "16187",
    "values": {
        "GROUP(trandate)": "22/06/2022",
        "GROUP(type)": {
            "value": "VendBill",
            "text": "Bill"
        },
        "GROUP(tranid)": "36380",
        "GROUP(location)": {
            "value": "140",
            "text": "ACBD"
        },
        "GROUP(custitem_item_category.item)": {
            "value": "13",
            "text": "Frozen Food"
        },
        "GROUP(custitem_item_subcategory.item)": {
            "value": "66",
            "text": "Frozen Fruits & Vegetables"
        },
        "GROUP(itemid.item)": "MN-FGGH10271310",
        "GROUP(displayname.item)": "ABC Product",
        "GROUP(custcol_po_line_barcode)": "883638668390",
        "GROUP(locationquantityonhand.item)": "4",
        "SUM(quantity)": "1",
        "SUM(totalvalue.item)": "4460.831",
        "SUM(custcol_po_unit_price)": "8.00",
        "SUM(formulanumeric)": "0"
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get all the columns while loading saved search?

Comment: you need to create a search through your script in place of passing the static filters and columns you need to pass your created saved search filters.                                                                                                         
  you can get ss filters  and columns like this  `let ssRes = search.load({ id: 'saved search id'})
         let extfils = ssRes.filters
         let extcols = ssRes.columns` for creating save search refer `N/search` module

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this particular issue before but Netsuite does have an issue sorting by any formulaX column other than the first one so seeing this is not surprising.

If you have no selection criteria on the aggregate values you could:

- modify your search to have no summary types or formula numeric columns
- in the map phase group them by the original search's grouping columns (no governance cost)
- in the reduce phase calculate the values for the formulanumeric columns (no governance cost)
- proceed with your original reduce phase logic.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to my previous answer you can split your process into parts.

1. Modify you saved search to include column labels
2. Use N/task to schedule your search with a map reduce script as a dependency using `addInboundDependency`
3. If your search finishes successfully the map reduce script will be called with your search file
4. return the file from your getInputData phase. You'll have to modify your map/reduce script to handle a different format but if your search can complete at all you'll be able to process it.

Below is a fragment of a script that does this but uses a schedules script as the dependency. Map/reduce scripts are also supported.

```js
var filePath = folderPath+ (folderPath.length ? '/' : '') + name;
var searchTask = task.create({
    taskType: task.TaskType.SEARCH,
    savedSearchId: searchId,
    filePath: filePath
});
var dependency = task.create({
    taskType:task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT,
    scriptId:'customscript_kotn_s3_defer_transfer',
    deploymentId:deferredDeployment,
    params:{
        custscript_kotn_deferred_s3_folder:  me.getParameter({name:'custscript_kotn_s3_folder'}),
        custscript_kotn_deferred_s3_file: filePath
    }
});
searchTask.addInboundDependency(dependency);
var taskId = searchTask.submit();
log.audit({
    title:'queued '+ name,
    details: taskId
});
```